# Python - multiprocessing while writing to a single result file

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am really new to the multiprocessing package and I am failing to get the task done.

I have lots of calculations to do on a list of objects.

The results I need to write down are saved in those objects, too.

The results should be written in a single file as soon as the process finished the calculations (the way I got it at least working, waits until all calculations are done).

```
import multiprocessing 
import time
import csv

class simpl():
    def __init__(self, name, val):
        self.name = name
        self.val = val

def pot_val(inpt):
    print("Process %s\t ..." % (inpt.name))
    old_v = inpt.val
    inpt.val *= inpt.val
    if old_v != 8:
            time.sleep(old_v)
    print("Process %s\t ... Done" % (inpt.name))


def mp_worker(inpt):
    pot_val(inpt)
    return inpt

def mp_handler(data_list):
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    with open('results.csv', 'a') as f:
        res = p.map_async(mp_worker, data_list)
        results = (res.get())
        for result in results:
            print("Writing result for ",result.name)
            writer= csv.writer(f, lineterminator = '\n', delimiter=";")
            writer.writerow((result.name, result.val))
if __name__=='__main__':
    data = []
    counter=0
    for i in range(10):
        data.append(simpl("name"+str(counter),counter))
        counter += 1    

    for d in data:
        print(d.name, d.val)
    mp_handler(data)
```

How to write the results from the calculations simultaneously to one single file, without having to wait for all processes to finish?

Comment: This is quite a story. Are there any questions as well?

Comment: Sorry, I changed it to a question :)

Comment: Does ordering of the results matter?

Comment: Ordering doesnt matter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [imap_unordered](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap_unordered)

```
def mp_handler(data_list):
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    with open('results.csv', 'a') as f:
        writer= csv.writer(f, lineterminator = '\n', delimiter=";")
        for result in p.imap_unordered(mp_worker, data_list):
            print("Writing result for ",result.name)
            writer.writerow((result.name, result.val))
```

With Python 3.3+ better do

```
def mp_handler(data_list):
    with multiprocessing.Pool(4) as p:
        with open('results.csv', 'a') as f:
            writer= csv.writer(f, lineterminator = '\n', delimiter=";")
            for result in p.imap_unordered(mp_worker, data_list):
                print("Writing result for ",result.name)
                writer.writerow((result.name, result.val))
```

Comment: Just a sidenote question: How would I catch a KeyboardInterrupt Exception in this construct? I tried wrapping an try: except: around 'with open..' but it still does output the whole exception for the workers.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know - apart from the obvious solution you tried. A good strategy for finding out if unexpected behavior is cause by havving multiple processes is replacing `multiprocessing` with `multiprocessing.dummy` which uses threads. Sometimes (especially on Windows)  you even have better performance with `multiprocessing.dummy`